# How long does it usually take to obtain a Sri Lankan Electronic Travel Authorisation (ETL) online?

Tags: visas, sri-lanka

It is possible to apply for an Electronic Travel Authorisation (ETL) to Sri Lanka [online](http://www.eta.gov.lk/slvisa/visainfo/center.jsp?locale=en_US).

Roughly how long does it typically take for an ETL to be issued once the application has been made?

In case it makes any difference, I am an Australian citizen looking to obtain a 30 day tourist visa.  Everything should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was practically instantaneous for my wife and when we applied a year ago. I submitted the online application on 28 January 2013 21:05 and received the approval on 28 January 2013 21:10, and my wife had an identical experience. We were also applying for a 30 day tourist  visa.

In case you think nationality might be relevant (it could be): We were both travelling with Irish passports, flying in from Chennai, India.

Comment: I had the same experience - a couple of minutes after the payment I received a confirmation email.