# Sri Lanka: visa requirements and possibility of visa on arrival at airport?

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, sri-lanka

I'm am European (French) and plan a holiday in Sri Lanka.

Do I need to apply for a visa to stay there for 3 weeks?

If yes, do I have to get the visa before going there (ie. through ambassy) or can I simply get it when I arrive (at the airport)?

I found this [ETA website](http://www.eta.gov.lk/) for the electronic visa but it kinda looks old so I'm unsure if I should take this seriously.

Comment: oh, just came across this thread http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23420/how-long-does-it-usually-take-to-obtain-a-sri-lankan-electronic-travel-authorisa , this website seems legit then. Any answer with further details still appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can purchase a visa on arrival by paying USD or Sri Lankan rupees.

The ETA website does work, despite not looking very slick.

I've tried out both methods as I typed in my passport number incorrectly to the ETA website. Immigration did not accept by online ETA receipt as it didn't match my passport.  I was then forced to purchase the ETA on the spot.

Comment: "I was then forced to purchase the ETA on the spot": did they use a knife ? :D

Comment: @AdrienBe Well, I guess I could have not purchased one and found a flight home instead :)

Comment: haha. not the kind of holidays you were planning I guess

Answer (score 2):

According to [this website](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=LK&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=IS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), citizens of almost any country, with a few exceptions listed on the page, can obtain a visa on arrival for up to 30 days.